# Does CSS content-visibility: hidden modify a DOM?

Tags: css

There's a new CSS property `content-visibility`.
Does it modify a DOM when set to `hidden` value?

Comment: CSS **never** modifies the DOM. CSS is combined with DOM to form the box tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not modify the DOM.

> Some great use cases for content-visibility: hidden are when implementing advanced virtual scrollers, and measuring layout. They're also great for single-page applications (SPA's). Inactive app views can be left in the DOM with content-visibility: hidden applied to prevent their display but maintain their cached state. This makes the view quick to render when it becomes active again.

Reference: https://web.dev/content-visibility/